# Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to accounts.google.com:443

Tags: r, ssl

I'm running a script that logs in to a google account and then downloads a list of queries from google trends. Previously, I could download a lot of queries, but lately (as in the last couple of days) the script returns the following error message after downloading the first 40-50 queries:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE):
 Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to accounts.google.com:443
```

Any ideas as to what is causing this problem?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958453/curl-error-35-unknown-ssl-google-oauth2) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234140/curl-error-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection) for possible solutions.  It may that the certificate fails to be verified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The pages you refer me to are a bit advanced given my programming skills. Is there an explanation for why the error is not present immediately, but after 40-50 queries?

Comment: It might be also a anti-bot protection from google. For tasks like this there is usually an official API which you should use (and pay for if you do lots of queries).